# I can't ask another question is something wrong?

Tags: support

According to the site I've asked 4 questions that weren't received well by the community and so I can't post another question for four days.

But I checked [my profile](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/8603/leeand00), and I only have one question with 3 down votes, so why can't I post another question?  Is the site malfunctioning?

Comment: You have four deleted questions as well, all of which are fairly downvoted - given you just asked one, it's possible it's temporarily rate limited (you just posted one). I'm actually not 100% sure how that works but I _think_ it manifests itself as that warning. I'll investigate that further.

Comment: @enderland it's a warning, see eg [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542/839601)

Comment: @enderland thank you!